# Stopping a variable increase unless another variable = max

Tags: javascript

I have a skill calculator which has been working fine for me for awhile but has always been missing something i couldn't get my head around as someone with no javascript experience.

What im trying to add is, i don't want skill 2 to increase unless skill 1 = max but skill 3 not to increase unless skill 2 = above 5 and skill 4 not to increase unless skill 2 and 3 = max.

Does that make sense? Im confusing myself a little here. any help or a point in the right direction would be amazing, thanks guys.

my skill calculator:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    var SkillManager = (function() {
        var max = 50,
            skills = {
                skill1: {
                    cur: 0,
                    max: 10
                },
                skill2: {
                    cur: 0,
                    max: 10
                },
                skill3: {
                    cur: 0,
                    max: 10
                },
                skill4: {
                    cur: 0,
                    max: 10
                }
            },
            totalUsed = 0;

var increase = function(skill) {
    if (totalUsed < max && skills[skill].cur < skills[skill].max) {
        skills[skill].cur++;
        totalUsed++;
        updateDisplay(skill, skills[skill].cur, max - totalUsed);
    } else if(skills[skill].cur === skills[skill].max) {
        alert("You have maxed out that skill!");
    } else {
        alert("You have used all your skill points!");
    }
};

var decrease = function(skill) {
    if (skills[skill].cur > 0) {
        skills[skill].cur--;
        totalUsed--;
        updateDisplay(skill, skills[skill].cur, max - totalUsed);
    } else {
        alert("You can't decrease a skill with 0 points in it!");
    }
};

var updateDisplay = function(skill, value, totalRemaining) {
if(document.all){
    document.getElementById(skill + "counter").innerText = value;
    document.getElementById("remainingPoints").innerText = totalRemaining;
} else {
    document.getElementById(skill + "counter").textContent = value;
    document.getElementById("remainingPoints").textContent = totalRemaining;
}

};

return {
    decrease: decrease,
    increase: increase
};
}());

</script>
```

Comment: In your `increase` function, you can do something like `if(skill=="skill2" && skills["skill1"]["cur"]==skills["skill1"]["max"]){...}` and alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var increase = function(skill) {
    if(skill == 'skill2' && skills.skill1.cur < skills.skill1.max){
        alert('skill2 -> skill1 < ' + skills.skill1.max)
    } else if (skill == 'skill3' && skills.skill2.cur < 5) {
        alert('skill3 -> skill2 < 5')
    } else if (skill == 'skill4' && (skills.skill2.cur < skills.skill2.max || skills.skill3.cur < skills.skill3.max)) {
        alert('skill2 -> skill2 < ' + skills.skill2.max + ' or skill3 < ' + skills.skill3.max)
    } else if (totalUsed < max && skills[skill].cur < skills[skill].max) {
        skills[skill].cur++;
        totalUsed++;
        updateDisplay(skill, skills[skill].cur, max - totalUsed);
    } else if(skills[skill].cur === skills[skill].max) {
        alert("You have maxed out that skill!");
    } else {
        alert("You have used all your skill points!");
    }
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5ExX8/)

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're 99% home.

Just add another switch before you do your initial comparison that looks at which skills is being passed in, and then based on whatever logic you describe or want, just exit out of the method if the criteria isn't met.

so...

```
if(skill == 'skill2'){
     if(skills["skill1"].cur < skills["skill1"].max)
         return;

     //etc... whatever other tests you wish to run
 }

 if (totalUsed < max && skills[skill].cur < skills[skill].max) {

//the rest of your code
 }
```

Comment: doing this seems to stop the whole function, i become unable to increase any skill. from what i see it wont allow the function to run atall unless skill1=max which is impossible since im unable to increase skill1 :S

Comment: I didn't mean for you to copy and paste the code... just to see what I'm doing. Don't nest the entire thing in the condition above, obviously that won't work.  The point is that you want to look at the skill being passed in, and do your other comparisons before you increment anything. In your case if it's skill1 then go right to your if(totalUser... etc) clause. I adjusted my snippet to be clearer.